# Al reemplazar caracteres con StringBuilder me sale muchas letras

Tags: java

Al cambiar más de 2 letras de un texto me sale el texto en la consola varias veces y algunas letras las cambia, otras las cambia pero no reemplaza.

```
   public static void main(String... mitocode) {
    
    String texto = "H1sp4ano";                
                
    char a;
             
        StringBuilder Cambiarpalabra = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
            a = texto.charAt(i);                
                
                if (a == '4') {
                    Cambiarpalabra.append('a');
            }else {
                        Cambiarpalabra.append(a);
        
                         if (a == '1') {
                             Cambiarpalabra.append('i');
            }else {
                                Cambiarpalabra.append(a);
                    }

            
       System.out.println(Cambiarpalabra.toString());   
                    }
                }
```

Lo esperado: `Hispaano`
El resultado: `HH1issppaaannoo`

Comment: estoy investigando pero necesito cambiar por ejemplo el 4 x el a el 1 por la i el 5 por la s si uso lo del OR no me cambia todas ellas por solo a?

Comment: puse lo que me sale y lo que deberia no entiendo muy bien lo de el operador logico OR

Comment: bueno usa condicionales como else if ejemplo  `if (a == '1'){Cambiarpalabra.append('i');}else if(a=='4'){Cambiarpalabra.append('a');else{ Cambiarpalabra.append(a);}`

Comment: no olvides imprimir la variable cambiarpalabra fuera del bucle for y de querer agregar 5 po s considera otro else if si son varias ,quiza te convenga usar un switch case

Comment: vale ya lo recodifique no habia caido en el elseif era esa la clave ahora si que no me da cosas raras, una vez mas gracias  Dramaturgo!

Answer (score 1):

Están mal ubicados los if y los else. Intenta lo siguiente...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String texto = "H1sp4ano";
    char a;
    StringBuilder Cambiarpalabra = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
        a = texto.charAt(i);
        if (a == '4') {
            Cambiarpalabra.append('a');
        } else if (a == '1') {
            Cambiarpalabra.append('i');
        } else {
            Cambiarpalabra.append(a);
        }
        System.out.println(Cambiarpalabra.toString());
    }
}
```

Resultado final: "Hispaano"